# change menuitem based on scroll position using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, uinavigationbar

Changing the menu item in navigation bar based on scroll position using javascript.

i have changed the menu item on click. but don't know how to change the active menu item based on scroll position. I have tried getting the `pageYoffset`. it is a very long process and too looks like repetition. is this the right way to do it or is there an efficient way to do so.

HTML CODE:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li id="home" class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#homeSection"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li id="about" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutSection"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li id="skill" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#skillSection"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li id="work" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#workSection"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li id="contact" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contactSection"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let header = document.getElementById("navbarNav");
let btns = header.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to provide us with an example using codepen or some html + javascript code editor, your question is confused

Comment: Now i have edited my question. Can you suggest the changes to the javascript

Comment: This menu will not show anything.

What exactly do you want to do? Do you want this menu item to be fixed in a location independent of the user's scrolling?

Try to exemplify

Comment: The navigation bar is at fixed position. Vertically positioned at left side. When i scroll to some particular section the menu item to should change to the active section. For example if scroll to about section, The about tab in the navigation bar should change to active mode.

Comment: I think I understand, I'll put an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can be minimised using jquery. BUt if you want to use javascript alone, you will have a little longer code. Get the scolltop value of each section during scroll event and assign the active class

Answer (score 2):

I created an example in codepen that I think describes what you asked for.

In my example I left the navigation bar horizontal, but the example is what counts.

Basically as you go down the sections, the navigation bar updates the items as active depending on where the client's scroll bar is.

https://codepen.io/aks-jacoves/pen/KKdYEPe?editors=1111

```js
$(window).on('scroll', e => {
  $('h2').each(function() {
    if($(this).offset().top - 200 < $(window).scrollTop()) {
      let id = '#' + $(this).text().toLowerCase()
      $('li').removeClass('active')
      $('li' + id).addClass('active')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li id="home" class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#homeSection"><i class="fa fa-home">Home</i></a>
            </li>
            <li id="about" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutSection"><i class="fa fa-user">About</i></a>
            </li>
            <li id="skill" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#skillSection"><i class="fa fa-cogs">Skill</i></a>
            </li>
            <li id="work" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#workSection"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li id="contact" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contactSection"><i class="fa fa-envelope">Contact</i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

    <div id="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
      <h2 id="section1">Home</h2>
      <p>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.</p>
      <p>"Whenever you feel like criticizing any one," he told me, "just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had."</p>
      <p>He didn't say any more, but we've always been unusually communicative in a reserved way, and I understood that he meant a great deal more than that. In consequence, I'm inclined to reserve all judgments, a habit that has opened up many curious natures to me and also made me the victim of not a few veteran bores. The abnormal mind is quick to detect and attach itself to this quality when it appears in a normal person, and so it came about that in college I was unjustly accused of being a politician, because I was privy to the secret griefs of wild, unknown men. Most of the confidences were unsought-frequently I have feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity when I realized by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon; for the intimate revelations of young men, or at least the terms in which they express them, are usually plagiaristic and marred by obvious suppressions. Reserving judgments is a matter of infinite hope. I am still a little afraid of missing something if I forget that, as my father snobbishly suggested, and I snobbishly repeat, a sense of the fundamental decencies is parcelled out unequally at birth.</p>
      <p>And, after boasting this way of my tolerance, I come to the admission that it has a limit. Conduct may be founded on the hard rock or the wet marshes, but after a certain point I don't care what it's founded on. When I came back from the East last autumn I felt that I wanted the world to be in uniform and at a sort of moral attention forever; I wanted no more riotous excursions with privileged glimpses into the human heart. Only Gatsby, the man who gives his name to this book, was exempt from my reaction-Gatsby, who represented everything for which I have an unaffected scorn. If personality is an unbroken series of successful gestures, then there was something gorgeous about him, some heightened sensitivity to the promises of life, as if he were related to one of those intricate machines that register earthquakes ten thousand miles away. This responsiveness had nothing to do with that flabby impressionability which is dignified under the name of the "creative temperament"-it was an extraordinary gift for hope, a romantic readiness such as I have never found in any other person and which it is not likely I shall ever find again. No-Gatsby turned out all right at the end; it is what preyed on Gatsby, what foul dust floated in the wake of his dreams that temporarily closed out my interest in the abortive sorrows and short-winded elations of men.</p>

      <h2 id="section2">About</h2>

      <p>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.</p>
      <p>"Whenever you feel like criticizing any one," he told me, "just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had."</p>
      <p>He didn't say any more, but we've always been unusually communicative in a reserved way, and I understood that he meant a great deal more than that. In consequence, I'm inclined to reserve all judgments, a habit that has opened up many curious natures to me and also made me the victim of not a few veteran bores. The abnormal mind is quick to detect and attach itself to this quality when it appears in a normal person, and so it came about that in college I was unjustly accused of being a politician, because I was privy to the secret griefs of wild, unknown men. Most of the confidences were unsought-frequently I have feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity when I realized by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon; for the intimate revelations of young men, or at least the terms in which they express them, are usually plagiaristic and marred by obvious suppressions. Reserving judgments is a matter of infinite hope. I am still a little afraid of missing something if I forget that, as my father snobbishly suggested, and I snobbishly repeat, a sense of the fundamental decencies is parcelled out unequally at birth.</p>
      <p>And, after boasting this way of my tolerance, I come to the admission that it has a limit. Conduct may be founded on the hard rock or the wet marshes, but after a certain point I don't care what it's founded on. When I came back from the East last autumn I felt that I wanted the world to be in uniform and at a sort of moral attention forever; I wanted no more riotous excursions with privileged glimpses into the human heart. Only Gatsby, the man who gives his name to this book, was exempt from my reaction-Gatsby, who represented everything for which I have an unaffected scorn. If personality is an unbroken series of successful gestures, then there was something gorgeous about him, some heightened sensitivity to the promises of life, as if he were related to one of those intricate machines that register earthquakes ten thousand miles away. This responsiveness had nothing to do with that flabby impressionability which is dignified under the name of the "creative temperament"-it was an extraordinary gift for hope, a romantic readiness such as I have never found in any other person and which it is not likely I shall ever find again. No-Gatsby turned out all right at the end; it is what preyed on Gatsby, what foul dust floated in the wake of his dreams that temporarily closed out my interest in the abortive sorrows and short-winded elations of men.</p>
      
      <h2 id="section3">Skill</h2>

      <p>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.</p>
      <p>"Whenever you feel like criticizing any one," he told me, "just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had."</p>
      <p>He didn't say any more, but we've always been unusually communicative in a reserved way, and I understood that he meant a great deal more than that. In consequence, I'm inclined to reserve all judgments, a habit that has opened up many curious natures to me and also made me the victim of not a few veteran bores. The abnormal mind is quick to detect and attach itself to this quality when it appears in a normal person, and so it came about that in college I was unjustly accused of being a politician, because I was privy to the secret griefs of wild, unknown men. Most of the confidences were unsought-frequently I have feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity when I realized by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon; for the intimate revelations of young men, or at least the terms in which they express them, are usually plagiaristic and marred by obvious suppressions. Reserving judgments is a matter of infinite hope. I am still a little afraid of missing something if I forget that, as my father snobbishly suggested, and I snobbishly repeat, a sense of the fundamental decencies is parcelled out unequally at birth.</p>
      <p>And, after boasting this way of my tolerance, I come to the admission that it has a limit. Conduct may be founded on the hard rock or the wet marshes, but after a certain point I don't care what it's founded on. When I came back from the East last autumn I felt that I wanted the world to be in uniform and at a sort of moral attention forever; I wanted no more riotous excursions with privileged glimpses into the human heart. Only Gatsby, the man who gives his name to this book, was exempt from my reaction-Gatsby, who represented everything for which I have an unaffected scorn. If personality is an unbroken series of successful gestures, then there was something gorgeous about him, some heightened sensitivity to the promises of life, as if he were related to one of those intricate machines that register earthquakes ten thousand miles away. This responsiveness had nothing to do with that flabby impressionability which is dignified under the name of the "creative temperament"-it was an extraordinary gift for hope, a romantic readiness such as I have never found in any other person and which it is not likely I shall ever find again. No-Gatsby turned out all right at the end; it is what preyed on Gatsby, what foul dust floated in the wake of his dreams that temporarily closed out my interest in the abortive sorrows and short-winded elations of men.</p>
      
      <h2 id="section4">Contact</h2>

      <p>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.</p>
      <p>"Whenever you feel like criticizing any one," he told me, "just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had."</p>
      <p>He didn't say any more, but we've always been unusually communicative in a reserved way, and I understood that he meant a great deal more than that. In consequence, I'm inclined to reserve all judgments, a habit that has opened up many curious natures to me and also made me the victim of not a few veteran bores. The abnormal mind is quick to detect and attach itself to this quality when it appears in a normal person, and so it came about that in college I was unjustly accused of being a politician, because I was privy to the secret griefs of wild, unknown men. Most of the confidences were unsought-frequently I have feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity when I realized by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon; for the intimate revelations of young men, or at least the terms in which they express them, are usually plagiaristic and marred by obvious suppressions. Reserving judgments is a matter of infinite hope. I am still a little afraid of missing something if I forget that, as my father snobbishly suggested, and I snobbishly repeat, a sense of the fundamental decencies is parcelled out unequally at birth.</p>
    </div>
```

See if this is what you wanted and if you have any questions, comment.

**Note:** open the code using codepen, here the navigation bar is not loading correctly